# Lines are Parallel iff their Corresponding Angles amongst a Traversal are Congruent.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Fellow Mathers, to any who could provide an insightful proof as to why this is true, Thank You.

> **Lines are Parallel iff their Corresponding Angles amongst a Traversal are Congruent.**

.

Definitions/Axioms used:

• Traversal: a line T such that given two other lines J and I: (T⋂J)⋃(T⋂I)= {P<sub>j</sub> , P<sub>i</sub>}

• Corresponding Angles: Given this traversal create 8 angles, the corresponding angles here are the ones that: (a) do not share a vertex, (b) lie on the same side of T, & (c) if one angle is in the interior of the two lines, the other is its exterior.

• Parallel Line: a line G is parallel to another line F if: F⋂G=ϕ

• Thru any point P not collinear to another line L, there exists one and only one line thru P parallel to L. (Parallel Postulate)

Comment: What axioms and/or theorems about parallel lines and angles do you already know? ... With fundamental geometric results like this, different textbooks/instructors/etc may present various theorems in different orders to suit a particular pedagogical flow. So, it's important to clarify what specifically may be assumed here.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3374770/edit) to include clarifications. Comments are easily overlooked.

Comment: You could follow the classic proof by Hilbert (beginning of §10 in 1950 English translation of "Foundations of Geometry"), but that depends on which axioms and theorems you are using: your list is very partial.

Comment: Thanks for the reference